# Boost a document based on the existence of a field

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to boost a document's relevance based on the presence of a field? I've read about [function score queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost-field.html#function-score-instead-of-boost) but I'm wondering how existence is taken into account - from my understanding, the `field_value_factor` applies to the content of the field, not on its presence.

Answer (score 1):

Function score query is a possibility, however a score function is computationally expensive and not necessary (keep in mind `exists` query used below may not have been available in 2014).

Can do the following:

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "should" : [
        { 
          match_all: {
            "boost": 10
          } 
        },
        {
         "exists": {
           "field": "some_field_that_should_exist"
          }
        }           
      ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 2,
    }
  }
}
```

With a minimum should match of 2 we say that both clauses must match in order for the should clause to match. This prevents the boost from being applied to documents that do not have the field.

Comment: Doesn't this only match if the field exists?

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified. Exists is a constant score query, boost can be used with it directly.

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "exists":{  
         "field":"some_field_that_should_exist",
         "boost":10
      }
   }
}
```